# Merging 3 dictionaries into single dictionary

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, merge

```
I have the following 

Dictionary<string,string> dict1 has 3 items
"A"="1.1"
"B"="2.1"
"C"="3.1"

Dictionary<string,string> dict2 has 3 items
"A"="1.2"
"B"="2.2"
"C"="3.2"

Dictionary<string,string> dict2 has 3 items
"A"="1.3"
"B"="2.3"
"C"="3.3"

I want a final Dict dictFinal which is of type Dictionary<string,string[]>

"A"="1.1,1.2,1.3"
"B"="2.1,2.2,2.3"
"C"="3.1,3.2,3.3"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given similar keys, provide a collection of all the dictionaries and use `SelectMany` to handle a dynamic number of array items:

```
var dictionaries = new[] { dict1, dict2, dict3 };
var result = dictionaries.SelectMany(dict => dict)
                         .GroupBy(o => o.Key)
                         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                                       g => g.Select(o => o.Value).ToArray());
```

The `dictionaries` type could be a `List<T>` not necessarily an array as above. The important thing is that you group them together in a collection in order to LINQ over them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all 3 dictionaries have the same keys, the following should do the job:

```
var d1 = new Dictionary<string, string>()
             {
                 {"A", "1.1"},
                 {"B", "2.1"},
                 {"C", "3.1"}
             };
var d2 = new Dictionary<string, string>()
             {
                 {"A", "1.2"},
                 {"B", "2.2"},
                 {"C", "3.2"}
             };

var d3 = new Dictionary<string, string>()
             {
                 {"A", "1.3"},
                 {"B", "2.3"},
                 {"C", "3.3"}
             };

var result = d1.Keys.ToDictionary(k => k, v => new[] {d1[v], d2[v], d3[v]});
```

Comment: If my array is dynamic, how can I add new d(x)[v] at runtime...!

Comment: @chugh97: see my response to handle dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all have the same keys the most straigt forward way is:

```
Dictionary<string,string[]> result = new Dictionary<string,string[]>();
foreach(var key in dict1.Keys)
{
    result[key] = new string[]{dict1[key], dict2[key], dict3[key]}; 
}
```